# Fetching contacts to a recycler view is too SLOW

Tags: android

I'm fetching contacts to recycler view... now the below codes just works great but it takes too much time on fetching contacts.... so if there is any way to get contacts fast than please guide me

```
public class AllContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllContactsAdapter.ContactViewHolder>{

private List<ContactVO> contactVOList;
private Context mContext;
public AllContactsAdapter(List<ContactVO> contactVOList, Context mContext){
    this.contactVOList = contactVOList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.single_contact_view, null);
    ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder = new ContactViewHolder(view);
    return contactViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ContactVO contactVO = contactVOList.get(position);

        holder.tvContactName.setText(contactVO.getContactName());
        holder.tvPhoneNumber.setText(contactVO.getContactNumber());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactVOList.size();
}

public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView ivContactImage;
    TextView tvContactName;
    TextView tvPhoneNumber;

    public ContactViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ivContactImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivContactImage);
        tvContactName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);
        tvPhoneNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNumber);
    }
}
}
```

This is where i'm fetching the contacts...

```
   private void getAllContacts() {
    List<ContactVO> contactVOList = new ArrayList();
    ContactVO contactVO;

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                contactVO = new ContactVO();
                contactVO.setContactName(name);

                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id},
                        null);
                if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    contactVO.setContactNumber(phoneNumber);
                }

                phoneCursor.close();

                Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String emailId = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                }
                contactVOList.add(contactVO);
            }
        }

        AllContactsAdapter contactAdapter = new AllContactsAdapter(contactVOList, getApplicationContext());
        rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rvContacts.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Where is code for fetching contacts ? You just showed your adapter code. Fetch your contacts in background and update your UI in UI thread.

Comment: oops sorry i missed

Comment: @Piyush please check it now

Comment: Use `AsyncTask` for fetch contacts in `doInBackGround()` method and update `UI` in `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: thanks @Piyush gonna check it using AsyncTask

Comment: You are creating too many objects, If you can reduce the no. of object creation then it will improve a lot.

Comment: user reactive programming approach for background task and updating ui its a new and useful thing

Comment: Like others suggested, do in background thread and i would also suggest to fetch the contacts in batches, not all at once.

Comment: facing again the same problem with AsyncTask  though.....

Comment: @Ritesh how to fetch the contacts in batches please can you explain it

Comment: It's like pagination, fetch 20 or 30 items at first and show it to the user and then fetch next 21 to 30 or 31 to 40 when user scrolls and reaches to the end offset.

Comment: Also, post the asynctask code you have written.

Comment: ok just tell me how to make if condition to get only 10 items in the above code??

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

I retrieve all Contacts and Bind that contacts into Listview (You can use also RecyclerView in your case)

### ContactsActivity

```
public class ContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String[] mProjection;
Cursor cursor;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

    mProjection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO
    };

    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
           mProjection,
           null,
           null,
           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC"
   );

   ContactListAdapter adapter = new ContactListAdapter(getContext(),cursor);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContactDisplay);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

### ContactListAdapter

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private Cursor mCursor;
String[] mProjection;

// State of the row that needs to show separator
private static final int SECTIONED_STATE = 1;

// State of the row that need not show separator
private static final int REGULAR_STATE = 2;

// Cache row states based on positions
private int[] mRowStates;

public ContactListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    mContext = context;
    mCursor = cursor;
    mRowStates = new int[getCount()];
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCursor.getCount();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    boolean showSeparator = false;
    mProjection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO
    };

    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_display_contacts, null);
    }
    else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    ImageView profileUser = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivProfileUser);
    TextView contactNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvUserContactName);
    TextView contactId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvUserContactId);
    contactId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    String id = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(mProjection[0]));
    String name = mCursor.getString( mCursor.getColumnIndex(mProjection[1]));
    int photo = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(mProjection[2]));

    contactNameView.setText( name );
    contactId.setText(id);

    if (photo == 0){
        profileUser.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_profile_user);
    }
    else {
        profileUser.setImageResource(photo);
    }

    switch (mRowStates[position]) {

        case SECTIONED_STATE:
            showSeparator = true;
            break;

        case REGULAR_STATE:
            showSeparator = false;
            break;

        default:

            if (position == 0) {
                showSeparator = true;
            }
            else {
                mCursor.moveToPosition(position - 1);

                String previousName = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(mProjection[1]));
                char[] previousNameArray = previousName.toCharArray();
                char[] nameArray = name.toCharArray();

                if (nameArray[0] != previousNameArray[0]) {
                    showSeparator = true;
                }
                mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            }

            // Cache it
            mRowStates[position] = showSeparator ? SECTIONED_STATE : REGULAR_STATE;

            break;
    }
    TextView separatorView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvContactAlphabetOrder);
    if (showSeparator) {
        separatorView.setText(name.toCharArray(), 0, 1);
        separatorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        view.findViewById(R.id.tvContactAlphabetOrder).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return view;
}
}
```

### row_display_contacts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvContactAlphabetOrder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="abc"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="#C8C8C8"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProfileUser"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_user"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUserContactName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abc"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/navigationBarColor"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUserContactId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abcdsfs"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/navigationBarColor"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

You can get all Contacts like this:

[image: Contact List]