# How to achieve contact list ui like ios in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to achieve contact list ui like as ios.

1)  alphabetical section index

2) Sticky headers

[image]

Comment: you can your third party lib for this

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/7724107/614807

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45181938/5908465

Comment: just google it https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=recyckerview+with+indexing&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=vClvWbmQFa_T8gf2kKDwAw

Comment: @NileshRathod : Have you any suggested library?

Comment: @ashish follow this link https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=recyckerview+with+indexing&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=vClvWbmQFa_T8gf2kKDwAw

Comment: You can make use of this library: https://github.com/DWorkS/AStickyHeader?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=670

Answer (score 1):

For Sticky Header library you can use the opensource library :- https://github.com/Arne517/sticky-headers-recyclerview

Comment: This link is unavailable :/